# I use two ckeditor control in an asp.net page but only 'image upload' option works for one of them

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

**Here is java script section**

$(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKEPage.ClientID %>', { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'Upload.ashx' });
            CKEDITOR.replace('<%=CKETeznote.ClientID %>', { filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'Upload1.ashx' }));
        });

Answer (score 0):

I could to solve the problem by put below code for each CKEditor control :

(CKEditor control ID).FilebrowserImageUploadUrl = "upload.ashx";

There is no need to javascript code anymore.